# Getting no output in custom python hash function

Tags: python

I have been making a python hash function ,and I have this so far.

```
keystring = [1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1]

bucket1 = []
bucket2 = []
bucket3 = []
bucket4 = []
while "1".lower() in keystring:
    if "1".lower() in keystring:
        bucket1.append(keystring[keystring.index("1") + 1])
        print (bucket1)
```

I have tried running it but it just says nothing ,and quits the program immediately.

Comment: the string "1" is not in the keystring.

Comment: Your `keystring` is an array of numbers, so it won't contain the string `"1"`. Remove the quotes (and the `.lower()`) in the `while` and `if` and `index`, or add quotes to your `keystring` values.

Answer (score 2):

```
while "1".lower() in keystring:
```

This is **never** true or, to better say, `True`.

In Python `"1"` is a string (`str`), which has the `.lower` method, which **returns a string**.

Since `keystring` is a `list` of `int`egers, you will never find a `str` in it, and the `while` loop will never begin.

Answer (score 0):

As @FLAK-ZOSO said you are searching for `str` in `while` loop.

1. You either can change the `keystring` items to `str` like this:

```py
keystring = ["1", "4", "2", "3", "2", "1", "4", "1"]

bucket1 = []
bucket2 = []
bucket3 = []
bucket4 = []

while "1" in keystring:
    if "1" in keystring:
        bucket1.append(keystring[keystring.index("1") + 1])
        print (bucket1)
```

2. Or you can change "numbers" in your `while` loop to `int`

```py
keystring = [1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1]

bucket1 = []
bucket2 = []
bucket3 = []
bucket4 = []

while 1 in keystring:
    if 1 in keystring:
        bucket1.append(keystring[keystring.index(1) + 1])
        print (bucket1)
```

I don't know "correct" way to  do it because I don' know context of your app but `for` loop might be better for this operation. And you are checking same thing in `if` statement as `while` loop. In `while` loop you are searching for 1 and then with `if` statement you are checking for 1 again which you already know it's there.

TLDR: You don't need `if` statement.